# Generating random numbers based on an inverse Gaussian distribution

Tags: python, gaussian

I can easily generate a random number along a gaussian/normal probability distribution.

```
slice = random.gauss(50.0, 15.0)
```

But the probability distribution is the inverse of what I want:

[image: normal probability distribution]

But what I want is the inverse probability.

Inverse of Gaussian probability looks like this:

[image: inverse Gaussian probability distribution]

And I would actually like to capture high probability not just for the left side, but also the right so.

So literally whatever the probability is of a result along a normal distribution...I want the actual probability of my results to be the opposite. So if it's 90% probability on a normal distribution, I want that result to appear 10% of the time, etc.

Comment: Way too much text. Remove everything except "I know how to get ... for a Gaussian distribution", and provide the code you would use. Then write your question - "how to do this for an inverse Gaussian" - and explain what an inverse Gaussian is (1/f? f such that Gaussian(f(x))=1? If there's a relevant `scipy` function write it, and that you don't know what the arguments mean.

Comment: You don't seem to use the meaning for "inverse Gaussian" as it usually is understood, since even with an inverse Gaussian the probability will go to 0 for when moving away from the mean. Remember that the definite integral from -infinity to infinity must be 1, not infinity. Have a look at the wiki page on [inverse Gaussian distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Gaussian_distribution).

Comment: I believe `mu` *is* the mean: https://brownmath.com/swt/symbol.htm

Comment: Jonathon, is there a way to set the standard deviation?

Comment: @Aro I'm not sure the second moment is defined for an inverse Gaussian. You can scale the function but that's not exactly the STD.

Answer (score 1):

While you work on editing your question, the answer can be found in the docs for scipy - check [invgauss](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.invgauss.html). Specifically,

```
from scipy.stats import invgauss
r = invgauss.rvs(mu, size=1000)
```

will generate a 1000 numbers drawn from an inverse Gaussian distribution centered around `mu` (your mean). To draw the `pdf`:

```
rv = invgauss(mu)
ax.plot(x, rv.pdf(x), 'k-', lw=2, label='frozen pdf')
```

for some axis object. To allow for more control you have:

```
invgauss.pdf(x, mu, loc, scale)
```

where `scale` in particular has a mathematical relationship to the STD, though I don't remember it offhand. The canonical form usually only depends on the mean.

Comment: @Aro The canonical form doesn't have that. I think setting the scale to STD, and the loc to the `mean` is what you want. `mu` is a shape parameter which standardizes that. The definition is in the page itself.